# Fast elements validation in an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have lists of students. In a list, some students can be active, and others can be inactive.

```
var allActive = [{id: 1, active: true}, {id: 2, active: true}, , {id: 3, active: true}];
var someNot = [{id: 4, active: true}, {id: 5, active: true}, , {id: 6, active: false}];
```

I want to check that a list has all students active. The easy way is just to use a for loop

```
for(var index = 0, student; student = array[index]; index++){
 if(stduent.active){
  return false;
 }
}
```

However, I do not want to create an additional piece of code like this. I want to use a quick way like forEach to check whether an array has all elements active.  What would be a quick way to do it using some of the built-in array functions?

Comment: This is not valid place to ask such kind of help. Go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and ask

Comment: will it help if you sort the array on the basis of active

Comment: @HarshPatel, this is a perfectly valid question for SO.

Comment: @HarshPatel I reckon it's the opposite: this question would be *off-topic* at Code Review.

Comment: @Pual We know that methods such as `forEach` are more elegant and readable... however, when it comes to performance (you said *"I want a quick way"*), almost nothing beats a `for` loop.

Comment: I totally agree. I wanted to have an idea about other native ways in javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the method [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to do so.  Here is an example

```js
var allActive = [{id: 1, active: true}, {id: 2, active: true}, , {id: 3, active: true}];

var someNot = [{id: 4, active: true}, {id: 5, active: true}, , {id: 6, active: false}];


console.log(allActive.every(entry=>entry.active)); // expected output: true
console.log(someNot.every(entry=>entry.active)); // expected output: false
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take a callback `isActive` which checks the property and use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for checking an array.

```js
function isActive(o) {
    return o.active === true;
}

var allActive = [{ id: 1, active: true }, { id: 2, active: true }, , { id: 3, active: true }],
    someNot = [{ id: 4, active: true }, { id: 5, active: true }, , { id: 6, active: false }];

console.log(allActive.every(isActive));
console.log(someNot.every(isActive));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `some`

```
var isOneFalse = array.some( s => s.active === false );
```

`isOneFalse` is true even if one active is `false`

Or you can modify as

```
var isAllTrue = !array.some( s => s.active === false );
```

`isAllTrue` is true only if all active is `true`